# Servlet not returning JSON to android

Tags: android, json, servlets

I am trying to send an image from android client to servlet.  I am using JSON to send encoded image and decoding in servlet.

When I run the servlet in eclipse I get 'null' on tomcat server console. And the same response is given when I tried to put printf statements for testing.

My servlet cose is:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    try
    {
    res.setContentType("application/json");
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "nocache");
    res.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    String jsonString = json.getString("image");

    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decodeBase64(jsonString.getBytes());//, Base64.DEFAULT);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\OWNER\\Desktop\\image.jpg");
    try {
        fos.write(decodedString);
    }
    finally {
        fos.close();
    }        

    // finally output the JSON with 1 for success
    JSONObject response=new JSONObject();
    out.println(response.put("result", 1).toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

}
```

The android code is:

```
class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                        HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                HttpEntity res;

                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                // Compress to jpg and convert to byte[]:

                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
                String imgData= Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
                String img=imgData.replace("\n", "%20");

                //add fields in JSON:

                JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject();

                jsonObject.put("img",data);

                httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(jsonObject.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));

                String sResponse = reader.readLine();
                return sResponse;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
            try {
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();

                if (sResponse != null) {
                    JSONObject JResponse = new JSONObject(sResponse);
                    int success = JResponse.getInt("result");
                    if (success == 1) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),

                                    "Photo uploaded successfully",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            caption.setText("");

                    } else {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>q</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Server1</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>q</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/P4</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

After launching app on android device, when upload button is pressed, there is no response. On the tomcat server I get 'null'.

How can I make this work? Thank you!

Comment: are you getting `out.println(response.put("result", 1).toString())` on server after upload button pressed?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK The only reponse I am getting on server is 'null'.

Comment: can you just show me url which you call form mobile side?

Comment: @DigveshPatel The URL is: http://192.168.1.104:8080/vaishnavee/P4 Here P4 is mapped to the above servlet code

Comment: server ???  means give me full url for that

Answer (score 1):

If your client side works right:

You should create json object base on request:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(req.getInputStream()));

    String jsonStr = "";
    if(br != null)
        jsonStr = br.readLine();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

Use `img` instead of `image`:

```
String jsonString = json.getString("img");
```

**Edit**: To debug your program at first write a simple example: a servlet that just return a simple json result. Test this servlet by firebug and firefox. Then add an android program that just call this servlet. If this simple program works right,then add other aspect of your program step by step and test your program at each step.

Comment: Gives  fromObject() method undefined

Comment: @vaishnavee: Don't try that, wait.

Comment: @vaishnavee: Are you using org.json library?

Comment: Yes that's the one i am using

Comment: Therefore, did you try this one?

Comment: @vaishnavee: Ok, which object is null? You should find it.

Comment: I tried to put printf stmnts for that purpose, but not a single stmnt is getting printed!What should i do?

Comment: @vaishnavee: When you `System.out.println` at first of doPost method. It is not called?

Comment: I put the print stmnt immediately after the opening of dopost , not getting printed. Just the 'null'

Comment: @vaishnavee: Attention to edited section of my answer, try that. If your problem will not be solved, inform me. We will chat about it in proper environment. sorry, now I should go. Good luck :)

Comment: I tried a simple code that returns a string wrapped in json to android. I could successfully run it. I tried to access this basic servlet with my android client to upload image and I could not get any response. The same code in basic android app to handle string in json did not work in required client i.e. the one uploading the image. I am not getting where am I going wrong! The response handling part in android is same and still it is not working!

Comment: Accessing servlet from your android client was successful? (without sending image, and just calling basic servlet)

Comment: Yes I called servlet from android,w/o sending image, successfully. I tried simple login: sent username and password by post and received json with result i.e. successful or failed. That worked fine.

Comment: @vaishnavee: Ok good :) Now add sending image section to android client (not receiving image to servlet). And print everything you get in servlet.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I shifted from servlet to web service with jersey,and took help of some tutorials.Now my application works fine. Thank you!

Comment: @vaishnavee: You're welcome. I'm so glad that your problem has been solved :)